# What's the best way to create several landing pages under a controller/action?

Tags: zend-framework

I am working with Zend Framework.

Currently I have a this structure http://mysite.com/page/promotion/

I would like to create several landing pages under the promotion, now I do it this way

```
    $promoId = $this->_getParam("id", false);

    if($promoId) {
        switch ($promoId){
            case 1:
                $this->render('promofirst');
                break;
            case 2:
                $this->render('promosecond');
                break;
            case 3:
                $this->render('promothird');
                break;      
            case 4:
                $this->render('testpromotion');
                break;
            default:
                $this->render('promotion');
                break;
        }
    }
```

So I can reach my promotions like this: http://mysite.com/page/promotion/id/1

I think it's not a good way, what's the convention to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there are any such specific standard methods of doing so, depending upon complexity your method is ok as well. How I generally do it is,

http://mysite.com/page/promotion/promote/first

and in my controller I would do,

```
$promote = $this->_getParam("promote", false);

if($promote) {
   $this->render('promo'.$promote);
} else {
   $this->render('promotion');
}
```

but then you will probably have to name your views in the same manner.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of to something like this:

```
//get the promo from where ever you have it stored and put it into a model
$model = new My_Promo_Model();
$promoId = $this->_getParam("id", false);

    if (!is_null($promoId)) {
        //structure the data in your model, not in the controller if possible.
        $promo = $model->getPromo($promoId);
        $this->view->promo = $promo;
    } else {
        //do some error stuff
    }
```

All of your promotions should probably be very similar in form and layout. Requiring only differing information and art to differentiate them. A simple entity model should be able to supply the from whatever your data source is to a view script.

If every promo requires a completely different viewscript you probably need to reconsider the structure of your pages.

if you need to use a few different layouts for different styles of promos that can be done with alternate layouts.

Good Luck.